# How do I sum multiple rows and show all columns?

Tags: mysql

[Picture of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMUBN.png)

[image]

```
SELECT *, SUM(match_attendance) FROM new_dashboard
Group BY worldcup_year;
```

I used this but don't know if it is correct? Is there like a proper way to do it? Via subquery or what not? Cause Im not sure showing if this is how people do it. I notice alot list all the column they wish to select then use the sum function but if you have like 20 columns that don't make sense.

Comment: I forgot to change the image name. So if anyone wish to view the image, just click on the enter image description here

Comment: _"don't know if it is correct?"_ - neither do we. Does it give the answer you want? If it does then it's correct.

Comment: Please show an example of exactly what results you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but it is not a good query. If you use where clause for a particular worldcup_year against this query, you will get only the first row of your required result-set. "SELECT *, SUM(match_attendance) FROM new_dashboard where worldcup_year='<your condition>'
Group BY worldcup_year;". So, try to avoid these type of query.

Comment: @kmoser What I wanted was the highest match attendance but showing the whole row of information

Comment: @SudiptaBhattacharyya Using the Where query means I am finding based off a specific year. However I want the SQL query to auto populate the row and year which is the highest match attendance. 

For example there are multiple matches in a year.

Comment: I added the picture on the link above. And sorry for the late reply. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @JoseJondoe Highest match attendance overall, or per year? It's not clear whether the example you showed is the data you are starting with, or the desired results. If it's the desired results, what is wrong exactly? You seem to have all the columns you are asking for.

Comment: @kmoser the sum would be the cumulative match attendance in a year. I understand I received the desired result but would this be accurate way of presenting a query? Or is there a more professional way? Thanks so much for helping!